NEED HELP DOING A CLEAN INSTALLATION OF WINDOWS FROM A USB DRIVE In Lenovo IdeaPad 110
I am trying to do with clean install of Windows from a USB drive where I use the media creation tool. I deleted all the partitions when it asked where I wanted to install windows. Now the only two partitions left say windows can't be installed in that partition.

i change all of setting in bios like like Legace and UEFI First

It also doesn't allow me to create a new partition. Can anyone please help? There is nothing on the computer that I want to save I just need a clean install of Windows 10
Even i use DISKPART by Use the Shotkey Shift+F10 and use below command:

Open Command Prompt,

type diskpart, and press Enter.

Type and Enter: list disk

Type and enter: select disk X

Type and press Enter: clean


but when I use Clean , diskPart get Error that say :
Diskpart has encountered an error : A device which dosen't exist was specified.
PLease HELP ME :(
images link:

https://i.sstatic.net/nS9BOavP.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/v85LrbMo.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/6ofJocBM.jpg


I don't "do" windows, but looking at your second image there was an option to delete the partitions.  Do that and restart the install process.

thank you davidgo but in the second image I can't delete or format any partition . when I do that i get error

Delete the partitions then choose the unallocated partition or simply enable CSM since the disk is MBR instead of GPT. Use the Delete option instead of using Diskpart. As your providing specifics on the error, cleanup your question, and remove “please help” and other unnecessary commentary from your question

I would try zero out the first 4k of the disk so it looks to the OS like it is unpartitioned.  Unfortunately I only know how to do this in Linux, not Windows.

Thank you @Ramhound For your answer ... But I can't do anything on this disk drive like delete the partition, create a new partition, or format the partition --- all commands don't work .... I think the disk is damaged

Thank you @davidgo ... I will search about topic you mentioned.... I hope this topic help me

@SeyedMortezaMousavifar - What commands? You can't hit the Delete button with the huge red X or when you do does it generate an error? If you suspect a disk error, you need to confirm, the disk is indeed failing before we can help you.

" I deleted all the partitions when it asked where I wanted to install windows. Now the only two partitions left say windows can't be installed in that partition." Delete all mean ALL, not leaving two partitions. To make it all empty space, boot from USB. You cannot remove a mounted partition.

How is it that diskpart show a 931 GB drive 0 and the "Windows Setup" window shows a 477 GB drive 0? Maybe window needs to be refreshed.

@DrMoishePippik hi , I boot from USB but i cant do anything command like "Delete Partition" or "delete Volume " and etc.... all of them got error.

I guess @davidgo and Ramhound are right and the disk is indeed failing...I have to replace hdd hard with a new one ssd . thank you All dear friends

@DavidAnderson Diskpart show all of the Capacity of Hard disk but windows setup show only partitioned drive that i created only one partition by size 477GB from 931 GB before the disk is indeed failing

@SeyedMortezaMousavifar: I would expect Windows Setup to have shown the difference as Unallocated Space. You image does not show any Unallocated Space.

@DavidAnderson : You are right David.... picture no 1 and 2 downloaded from the internet but the third image is mine.... thank you for Your high precision

the disk is indeed failing .. thank you all Friends
